# Clojure not recognizing parent classes

Tags: casting, clojure, jax-ws

I'm writing using wsimport to generate a client for a web service, however, when I try to initiate the binding with an Addressing feature, I get the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature cannot be cast to [Ljavax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;`

I know for a fact that javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature extends javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature, so I'm not sure what's happening. I know you cannot downcast in Clojure, but casting to a parent should work.

From my understanding, objects should be autocast, and if they are not, `clojure.core/cast` should work, however, both throw an exception.

My code looks something like this:

```
(-> (com.test.TestAPISOAP.) 
    (.getTestWSHttpBinding 
        (javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature. true true)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `.getTestWSHttpBinding` accepts an array (the [L in [Ljavax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature), not a single element.

Try creating an array with `AddressingFeature` as a single element using [clojure.core/to-array](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/to-array):

```
(-> (com.test.TestAPISOAP.) 
    (.getTestWSHttpBinding 
        (to-array [(javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature. true true)])))
```

Comment: Thanks! I overlooked the array aspect of it.